# Slice a compact C1 surface in R3 by a moving transverse plane. Does the length of the slice depend C1 on the plane?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-calculus

To be more precise I am interested in questions similar to the one below
(I asked the question below on math.stackexchange last week but got not answer.)

I have a $C^1$ function $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
The arclength of the graph of $f_y:x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is
$$L(y)=\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right)^2} dx$$
Deriving under the integral does not seem to be possible since it would involve a crossed derivative $\partial^2 f/\partial x\partial y$ whose existence is not assumed. Hence I do not expect L to always be a $C^1$ function of y. But so far I have not been able to find a counterexample.
This question must have been already looked at. Any idea?

Comment: The way I see it, it doesn't even need to be continuous. An extreme example: take a cylinder and cut it by planes parallel to the axis: at some point, the length changes from $\infty$ to $0$.

Comment: I think the difficult-looking appearance of your question has to do with your choice of coordinates.  If instead of comparing the Riemann metric on your curves to the domain of $f$, i.e. $[0,1]$ you compare them directly, you get a much better sense for how the length varies.  If your two curves are uniformly $C^1$-close, orthogonal projection from one to the other (using the normal line to the tangent space) gives a natural map between the two and allows you to compare their lengths with less bias.  I think if you write out the details this answers your question.

Comment: OK Alex, the title is bad, I will change it if I can.

Comment: Alex's argument works just as well for any compact surface containing a line segment. Take the surface of a cube, and then slightly smooth out the corners and the edges. Length of intersection is not defined along planes that hit the faces. Or take a cigar: cap off a finite length cylinder with two spherical caps. Then your length of intersection jumps up from zero to positive suddenly.

Comment: You are right, Ben. I am so sorry to be unable formulate a title right. What I meant is really the question that is asked, not its title.